# apply custom filter to $_GET variables everywhere everytime codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, input-filtering

I need to trim every `$this->input->get('q', true);` in my projects. is there a way to do this instead of adding `trim()` every time?

Naim Malek told me to use helper, but I don't quite understand how it would work in this case..

Comment: Go to application/helper create a file like this MY_html_helper.php inside this file create a funtion with any name you want. Inside that function return input post with trim and you can use that function directly in controllers

Comment: thanks for the reply @AmarjytChahal, but I believe your method would require to change every `$this->input->get()` in the project.. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [hooks](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html) for trimming every 'q' get parameter.

First enable hooks in ***application/config/config.php***

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

Then create a file with custom name (example: Trim_hooks.php) in ***application/hooks*** and write below code in hook config file(***application/config/hooks.php***) file.

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
    'class' => 'Trim_hook',
    'function' => 'run',
    'filename' => 'Trim_hooks.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
);
```

At the end create ***Trim_hooks.php*** file in ***application/hooks***:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Trim_hook
{
  function run()
  {
    if (isset($_GET['q']))
    {
      $_GET['q'] = trim($_GET['q']);
    }
  }
}
```

Every time you have q parameter in GET, it's trimming after run controllers constructoror.

Comment: I'm a little confused.. where should I put the $hook array? is it inside the class Trim_hook?

Comment: Sorry, i missed it. Write $hook array in **application/config/hooks.php**.

Comment: is it ok to use a different index for $hook? e.g. $hook['after_controller_constructor']? it's not included in the documentation..

Comment: available hook points included in [Hooks Points](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html#hook-points)